# How to check files associated with some label in perforce are synced or not?

Tags: python, perforce

I have a perforce label with which i am retrieving files associated with it as follows:

```
p4 files @my_label_name
```

this command retrieves me the list of files against the label "my_label_name".Now, i want to check that these files in my workspace are synced to latest or not.How shall i do it?
I searched on net and got a command as:

```
p4 sync -n -m 1
```

but with this command whole workspace is checked weather its up to date or not but i am only interested about status of the files associated with label of my wish. So, kindly suggest how can i have this.

Answer (score 2):

It's not 100% clear which of these you want, so I'll give you 3 different commands to experiment with:

```
p4 sync -n -m1 @my_label_name
```

i.e. "is my workspace in sync with this label?"

```
p4 sync -n -m1 @my_label_name,@my_label_name
```

i.e. "is my workspace in sync with this label if I ignore files not in the label?"

```
p4 sync -n -m1 @my_label_name,#head
```

i.e. "which of the files in this label do I not currently have synced to #head?"